# Bukkit countdown timer happening after event

Tags: java, plugins, runnable, bukkit, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a Bukkit plugin that warps a player randomly every five minutes. I figured out the warp, but my countdown is happening after the player warps and I want to make it happen before.
Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Here's my code:

```
public class Commands implements Listener, CommandExecutor {


public String cmd0 = "startwarp";

private main plugin  = main.getPlugin(main.class);

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if(sender instanceof Player) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cmd0)) {

            if(args.length == 0) { 


                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Warp timer begun!");
                Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable(){
                            int countdown;
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (countdown >= 1) { 
                                    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + " " + countdown + "...");
                                    countdown--;
                                }

                            }
                        }, 0, 1 * 20);

                        Location loc = player.getLocation();
                        int randX = (int) (loc.getBlockX() + ((Math.random() * 1000) - 500));
                        int randZ = (int) (loc.getBlockZ() + ((Math.random() * 1000) - 500));
                        int randY = (int) ((Math.random() * 240) + 15);
                        Location randomtp = new Location(player.getWorld(), randX, randY, randZ);
                        player.teleport(randomtp);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Teleported!");
                        //warpTimer timer = new warpTimer();
                        //timer.runTaskTimer(plugin, 0, 1 * 20);

                    }
                }, 5 * 60 * 20, 5 * 60 * 20);
            }
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Timer starts before the player gets teleported, but the code doesnt wait until the timer is finished, before executing the rest of the code. Try this:

```
int countdown = 10
new BukkitRunnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (countdown >= 1) {
      Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMesssage(countdown);
      countdown--;
    } else {
      Location loc = player.getLocation();
      int randX = (int) (loc.getBlockX() + ((Math.random() * 1000) - 500));
      int randZ = (int) (loc.getBlockZ() + ((Math.random() * 1000) - 500));
      int randY = (int) ((Math.random() * 240) + 15);
      Location randomtp = new Location(player.getWorld(), randX, randY, randZ);
      player.teleport(randomtp);
      player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Teleported!");
      cancel();
    }

  }.runRepeatingTask(*instanceOfMainClass*, 0, 20);

}
```

This code is handwritten and out of my mind, so maybe there are a few mistakes.